# How can "life" begin at "conception"?

Tags: philosophy-of-science, philosophy-of-language

If the cells that come together and develop into a fetus are "alive" and "living", how can "life" begin at "conception"? "Life" began billions of years ago

Comment: The argument is **human** life begins at conception.

Comment: What is more, *this particular human individual's life*

Comment: Nothing can begin, because everything arises from prior things. It's like Zeno's Paradox.

Comment: I could possibly answer the question of *How can life begin at conception*, but I don't know what you mean by *How can **"life"** begin at **"conception"***. The problem is why quotation marks?

Comment: @ScottRowe ... that's a ridiculous claim? Did you always exist? Hope not. At one point, the prior things become other things and there's a beginning

Comment: But when did the prior things become what they were? Where is the actual shore of the ocean, at a microscopic level? It doesn't exist.

Comment: @ScottRowe either nothing exists or things *do* exist and it's their specific atomic structure that makes them what they are. At the point in which atoms are structured the way that makes them a "shore", they begin to be a shore

Comment: So when do they reach that point?

Comment: @ScottRowe when the atoms are organized in their specific manners ...

Answer (score 1):

The word "life" has multiple meanings, obviously, and not a single one as implied by the question. For each meaning, the "beginning" is different.

The one mentioned in the question seems most closely linked to the meaning that is synonymous to "Personhood" which has a quite lengthy wikipedia page referencing more details than belong inside an answer on this site https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Personhood, and a separate article on the beginnings: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beginning_of_human_personhood: There are differences of opinion as to the precise time when human personhood begins and the nature of that status.

> Hippocrates and the Pythagoreans stated that fertilization marked the beginning of a human life

> According to Hinduism Today, Vedic literature states that the soul enters the body at conception

> Some medieval Christian theologians held that ensoulment occurs when an infant takes its first breath of air.

> St. Thomas Aquinas and St. Augustine of Hippo held the view that fetuses were "animated" (using Aristotle's term for ensoulment) near the **40th day after conception**

The other meaning of "life" mentioned in the question is more precisely to be  called "Life on earth", and the beginning is called Abiogenesis https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abiogenesis It is too complex to usefully represent as an answer on stackexchange.

In any case the ambiguity of the word "life" is too well known and obvious to be an important matter of philosophy. The issue of identity over time of life is also well known to not have an objective philosophical solution, same as the ship of Theseus paradox.

Answer (score -1):

This is a legitimate question -- that couples back to "what is human life".

The argument that life begins at conception is a pragmatic one -- and also a materially reductive one.  IE, reductively the origin of a new human was when two haploid cells combine to form a new and genetically unique diploid one.  Note the reduction to genetics is needed here, because both the egg and sperm are human life, as you implied.

There are problems with this simple formula.  As I noted, both egg and sperm are human, and alive.  They are also not "part of" the mother or father -- all diploid life goes through a two stage process, where it spend part of its life cycle as a diploid being, and part as a haploid.  Usually the macro scale entities are diploid, sometimes the macro scale are haploid.  Sometime *both* stages are multicellular!!!  Biology treats both stages as "that form of life" and distinguishes each stage as a separate individual.

Advocates of life at conception say to ignore all that -- pragmatically in humans we can "treat" sperm and eggs as part of the parents -- as they basically never get to develop into adults.  Note however, that many species that are normally haploid will produce diploid offspring when there are no males around to reproduce with.  IE full size wasps, etc sometimes are haploid.  This has been documented in mammals as well, with full haploid rabbits being triggered to develop in lab tests.

Also, identical twins are not "created" at conception, but a while after, when the splitting fertilized cell at its first division duplicates rather than specializing.

Biology is far more complex than this simple formula. Basically, life *is* a continuous series.   But you can mark when a new multicellular human is formed, that is when an egg cell begins specializing when it splits.

Even this formula will not work, however, when human cloning is achieved.

As I noted, biology is complex.  Trying to tie a theological concept to it -- will get tied up in knots.